# Should I remove return 0 as noise?

Tags: discussion, edits

It is quite common that questions about C has a code snippet that includes a `main` function that ends with `return 0`. You could argue that this is good practice, but I have not yet seen an example where this is actually relevant to the question.

Since `main` is the only function where you can omit the return statement, even though it is not declared as a void, the return statement is not required to make the code a mcve.

So can I remove it as noise?

Comment: No. Don't make edits to code.

Comment: @gnat don't really agree, this question is more about what falls under the definition of noise.

Comment: Of course the dupe answers it. "Don't Change code conventions." This person prefers including `return 0`, Broman prefers not including it. That's a convention, it's neither right nor wrong. It does not make a MCVE not minimal, just like the extra line to use Egyptian Brackets doesn't invalidate the minimality of an MCVE that uses them.

Answer (score 14):

No, don't make edits out of *style*. It bothers me ***to no end*** when I see people casting the return value of `malloc()` *in 2018* but the only reason to edit it would be if it's wrong or somehow dangerous.

But then, you should probably be politely pointing out something about type safety and function pointers in a comment and optionally using your down vote. Advocating good form isn't noise in the mind of the person that wrote the answer, so unless it's advocating something you know to be *bad*, there's really no action to take beyond yelling at your monitor.